# Static NSLocalizedString causes "one-time initialization function" crash only on iOS16

Tags: swift, crash, nslocalizedstring, ios16

We usually define `NSLocalizedString` as static variables in a `String` extension such as:

```
extension String {
    static let text = NSLocalizedString("text_key", tableName: "Translations", value: "text", comment:"")
}
```

Then we have some classes that uses this constant strings to initialize some variables such like:

```
class DummyClass {
   var randomText: String? = .text
}
```

Having said that, that approach worked fine until now. When iOS16 was released, we started seeing a lot of crashes related to this piece of code (only iOS16 sessions). Although, we can not reproduce this locally to investigate the causes, we know the crash happens on app startup.

Crash signature is `one-time initialization function for X`, where `X` is the name of the string constant, followed by `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Anyone can please advice what changed on iOS16 in regards to this? Did anyone face the a similar situation? How to fix the crash?

Comment: What happens if instead of `extension String` you use an enum e.g `enum L10n` to contain your strings.

Comment: We have the exact same crash using L10n as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

faced the same problem. did you use On-demand resources for your project? highly suspicious for ODR.

Comment:  We do have ODR in the project indeed. And actually we are having some other issue related to it. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @CRoig did you fix this issue? I am too facing the issue and we are also using ODR.

Comment: *@qidong* did you fix this issue?

Comment: Yes I did. That was totally related to ODR. We debounced the ODR fetch and problem got solved. Sorry for late reponse @venky

Comment: @CRoig how much delay did you give? I indeed fetching resources in scene delegate

Comment: @CRoig Can you detailed your solution? I'm facing the same issue but I can't get what do to about it. I don't really understand how strings are related to ODR either.